# Linq intersect to filter multiple criteria against list

Tags: c#, linq, intersect

I'm trying to filter users by department. The filter may contain multiple departments, the users may belong to multiple departments (n:m). I'm fiddling around with LINQ, but can't find the solution. Following example code uses simplified `Tuples` just to make it runnable, of course there are some real user objects.

Also on CSSharpPad, so you have some runnable code: http://csharppad.com/gist/34be3e2dd121ffc161c4

```
string Filter = "Dep1"; //can also contain multiple filters
var users = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create("Meyer", "Dep1"),
    Tuple.Create("Jackson", "Dep2"),
    Tuple.Create("Green", "Dep1;Dep2"),
    Tuple.Create("Brown", "Dep1")
};

//this is the line I can't get to work like I want to
var tuplets = users.Where(u => u.Item2.Intersect(Filter).Any());


if (tuplets.Distinct().ToList().Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in tuplets) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No results");
}
```

Right now it returns:

```
(Meyer, Dep1)
(Jackson, Dep2)
(Green, Dep1;Dep2)
(Brown, Dep1)
```

What I would want it to return is: *Meyer,Green,Brown*. If `Filter` would be set to `"Dep1;Dep2"` I would want to do an or-comparison and find *Meyer,Jackson,Green,Brown" (as well as distinct, as I don't want *Green* twice). If `Filter` would be set to `"Dep2"` I would only want to have *Jackson, Green*. I also played around with `.Split(';')`, but it got me nowhere.

Am I making sense? I have Users with single/multiple departments and want filtering for those departments. In my output I want to have all users from the specified department(s). The LINQ-magic is not so strong on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `string` implements `IEnumerable`, what you're doing right now is an `Intersect` on a `IEnumerable<char>` (i.e. you're checking each letter in the string). You need to split on `;` both on `Item2` and `Filter` and intersect those.

```
var tuplets = users.Where(u => 
    u.Item2.Split(new []{';'})
    .Intersect(Filter.Split(new []{';'}))
    .Any());
```

Comment: I like you additional explanation. Thanks!
I guess it is now only a matter of preference/readability `users.Where(u => u.Item2.Split(';').Any(f => filter.Split(';').Contains(f)));` vs. `users.Where(u => u.Item2.Split(';').Intersect(filter.Split(';')).Any());` - both do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] Filter = {"Dep1","Dep2"}; //Easier if this is an enumerable
        var users = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            Tuple.Create("Meyer", "Dep1"),
            Tuple.Create("Jackson", "Dep2"),
            Tuple.Create("Green", "Dep1;Dep2"),
            Tuple.Create("Brown", "Dep1")
        };

        //I would use Any/Split/Contains
        var tuplets = users.Where(u => Filter.Any(y=> u.Item2.Split(';').Contains(y)));


        if (tuplets.Distinct().ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in tuplets) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No results");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, the `Contains` extension method may also be a good fit for what you're trying to do if you're matching on a value:

```
var result = list.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.Value));
```

Otherwise, the `Any` method will accept a delegate:

```
var result = list.Where(x => filter.Any(y => y.Value == x.Value));
```